# Cron fails for WP site on Pantheon - although EasyCron reports success

Tags: cron, cron-job, pantheon

We are hosted on Pantheon.io and have a WordPress site with CiviCRM installed. The instructions from CiviCRM docs say, "In order for the scheduled jobs configured within the CiviCRM UI to run automatically, you'll need to configure a cron job which executes the Job.execute API call."
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#url-to-cronphp

This means a call to a cron.php file inside CiviCRM. The standard Pantheon cron program does not call CiviCRM cron. So I set up an EasyCron http call from outside Pantheon. According to EasyCron, the cron call to CiviCRM is successful every time. However, according to my CiviCRM System Status page, cron is not running at all. How bizarre. Here is the relevant Pantheon instruction:
https://docs.pantheon.io/guides/wordpress-developer/wordpress-cron#manage-wp-cron-externally

[image: EasyCron page]

[image: CiviCRM system status page]

Comment: Have you added the username/password and site key parameters to the URL? See the details in the user guide that you linked to for details. I'd suggest trying to call the URL from the command line to check that it works.